Which of these areas are mold risks or pest-intrusion risks vs just cosmetic imperfections?
I have just signed a lease on a place that was a deal I couldn't pass up with the knowledge I'll want to put some work in on it myself (landlord is not great), what would be considered problematic from a pest-intrusion and/or mold remediation perspective?
I want to determine what my next steps need to be and what to prioritize.















humidity and rot everywhere, lots of work to fix, ask the so friendly lord for permission

The pictures show various areas where there was once water intrusion and  very poor workmanship was done to mask the result.  There is no way to know if the origins of the problems were corrected so it is impossible to say if the poor "repairs" are cosmetic.  You will have to take each issue one at a time and see what transpires.

I legitimately lol'ed at the painted-over spray-foam. That really says "I just dgaf"
